# Reading contract's map

Tags: ink

Given a contract's state:

```rust
struct MyContract {
  my_map: Mapping<AccountId, BlockNumber>,
}
```

How can I efficiently read all of `my_map` entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here after some more digging...

There's no good solution to this in ink! 3 because `Mapping::storage_key` (used in [`Mapping::insert`](https://docs.rs/ink_storage/3.4.0/src/ink_storage/lazy/mapping.rs.html#130-136)) has the following [definition](https://docs.rs/ink_storage/3.4.0/src/ink_storage/lazy/mapping.rs.html#203):

```
fn storage_key<Q>(&self, key: &Q) -> Key
where
    Q: scale::EncodeLike<K>,
{
    let encodedable_key = (&self.offset_key, key);
    let mut output = <Blake2x256 as HashOutput>::Type::default();
    ink_env::hash_encoded::<Blake2x256, _>(&encodedable_key, &mut output);
    output.into()
}
```

It's blake2b hashing the `key` and map's offset before calling pallet's runtime. Meaning, even if we iterate over all keys in the map, we won't be able to recover the original `key` the value was stored under.

This is fixed ink! 4. See [[3]](https://docs.rs/ink_storage/4.0.0-alpha.3/src/ink_storage/lazy/mapping.rs.html#140) and [[4]](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11501) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read all of `my_map` entries because `Mapping` works on `key & value` and it has only `insert & get` operation through which you can  insert one element and get one element at one time.

If you want to efficiently read all of `my_map` entries then you can use `Vec` to store `key` like this:

use ink_prelude::vec::Vec;

```
struct MyContract {

     my_map: Mapping<AccountId, BlockNumber>,

     all_entries: Vec<AccountId>

}
```

and when you input new `my_map` you can do like this:

```
self.my_map.insert(AccountId, &BlockNumber)

self.all_entries.push(AccountId)
```

But `Vec` we are using from `use ink_prelude::vec::Vec;` has also caveat. It is fully loaded into the memory which is not appropriate for holding large amount of data. They are planning to migrate `ink_storage::Vec`, which is not available yet.

Comment: Hey Ganesh, thanks for the reply. I'm aware I can't read all of the map entries as return in `#[ink(message)]` -- I was interested how to do it via RPC and querying storage directly.

Comment: @deuszx you mean read all `my_map ` entries via RPC?